# Indicate previous "Close" reasons

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, close-reasons

When voting to close a question, it does not appear that there is a way to know what the previous close votes were. For example, if a question has 3 close votes already and I go to close the question as well, I have no way of knowing what those other 3 close votes were. A good example here would be a question that 3 people think belong on Super User but I think it belongs on Server Fault.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This feature already exists. Note the "(1)" and "(2)" by "belongs on serverfault.com" and "belongs on superuser.com" respectively. This indicates that 1 person voted to close as "belongs on serverfault.com" and 2 people voted to close as "belongs on superuser.com":

[image]

([screenshot taken from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1275050/whats-the-easiest-way-to-sniff-tcp-traffic-data-on-linux))

Comment: Awesome. Thank you for letting me cast the deciding vote on that. I did my evil laugh and said, "See you in he-SuperUser!" Then I clicked the button. I was hoping for a theme song or a *woooosh* sound, but all I got was a closed question.

Comment: Good thing I took a screenshot - I figured that posting the link would prompt people to actually close the question (and thus destroy the example)

Answer (score 2):

Yes you do. There is a little number next to each reason of previous votes.

Comment: Can't find an example right now, but yes, there are little numbers in (parenthisis) next to each reason that show other votes.